# how to detect a bin / box in pcl?

Tags: c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library, robotics, point-clouds

Hello I am new to PCL (point cloud library) and my task is to detect 3d objects in a box / bin using surflet pairs using kinect. I am able to segment and cluster some of the objects but my algorithm also detects the box as a segment. I want to know how can I detect and remove only the box in the scene ? 
should I use PCA or SIFT ?

Thank you,
Saransh Vora

Answer (score 0):

You could run a [planar ransac](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php) and subtract all points that belong to planes of sufficiently large sizes.  An additional specification would be to only subtract out planes that have a normal vector at nearly 90 degrees from unit-z.  This would allow you to search for smaller planes without fearing cutting your objects in your box too badly as it would make your filter highly specific to vertical planes.

Another note, if your box doesn't move... you could just save your (empty) point cloud ie the cloud when there are no objects in the box and then when you get a new cloud use that saved cloud as a proximity filter to cut out all points which are sufficiently close to what was labeled as background.